# STM32F103C8T6 fake?

Tags: usb, stm32

I have a curious problem:

**Prequel**: I "designed" a clone of the Black Magic Probe v2.1, which I like a lot but has IMHO some shortcomings (e.g. the 1.27mm-pitch connector to name just one). I got a PCB manufactured, programmed the DFU bootloader using the ST-bootloader (UART) and my clone works a charm, debugging and all.

**Problem**: I decided to solder up another one and got all the parts from LCSC.com along with the required STM32F103C8T6 µC powering the show. On this one I wasn't able to activate the ST-bootloader using UART. So I flashed the DFU bootloader using my good clone, which worked with no flaws. The DFU bootloader is then run as indicated by the LED flash pattern. But when I try to connect the clone to a PC, to DFU the firmware, there's no joy. I then flashed the firmware using SWD to the required offset, just to notice that there is no USB enum either. It is also possible to command the chip using a STlink.
I then changed to another Chip from the same LCSC-lot with the same behavior.
I even checked the soldering... ;)

So:

- No UART
- No Bootloader
- No USB
- GPIO seems to work (LEDs flash)

**Question**: Do I miss something or do these chips seem to be fake? How can I check?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'd suspect a design or assembly flaw first.  Try writing a program that generates UART output *without* needing any input.  Use the HSI clock.  Make sure you have the boot mode pins set appropriately.  Also try reading out the chip idcode.  I've not heard of any partially functional MCU fakes (vs completely different or non functional devices mislabeled as MCUs); some of the GigaDevices parts are *extremely* similar to ST's in terms of peripheral registers etc, but they're marketed under their own name.

Comment: It might be possible you could have a different STM32f10x family member mis-marked, but I'd expect the bootloader and UART to still work.  And SWD should give you visibility into what is going on - what address is it executing from or stuck at? 
 Until you can demonstrate that the same board works when you swap a chip of known origin onto it but not when you put back the one at issues, or until you are able to read a clearly different property, guessing "fake" is premature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I suspect(ed) a design/assembly flaw as well, but I can't find it; as I said, same PCB with STM32 from other source (reichelt.de) works perfectly. 
STlink utility identifies the µC correctly as STM32F10xx med density: https://imgur.com/a/F1olN65 ..working on that UART code; sorry for not coming up with that myself...

Comment: You need to carefully check your second board for tiny solder bridges, and clean it thoroughly with Isopropyl alcohol, and then dry it well, in an oven. It is possible that your system clock gets whacked by solder flux contamination, and/or some straps can also be off. Check power first, then RESET, then clocks.

Comment: Update. Using the suggested uart program I solved the uart/bootloader-problem: the resistor between TX of the level-shifter to the TXD-Pin was open (not 100R as exprected). So the UART-bootloader is now working perfectly. But USB is still inop. I will remove and bridge the USB ESD diodes next.
I checked for solderbridges (four times now... ;/)

Comment: It looks like you need to improve your soldering skills and technique. If you have one cold solder joint, there might be others. What kind of solder flux, solder, and soldering iron did you use, and at what temperature?.

Comment: Well; there was no cold solder joint; the actual resistor was broken, believe it or not. I measured continuity/resistance from the USB connector to the litteral case of the µC (thus including the solderjoint of the µC itself)....
As to the soldering the PCB was assemled using a SMD stencil and leaded solderpaste; then soldered using hot air at 375°C. After that some parts were touched up using leaded solder with a manual iron at 355°C using jellybean flux from china... :)

Comment: Your descriptions don't make sense.  You describe a UART problem, but you say you measured from the USB connector.  And then you propose *bridging* ESD diodes - if your diodes are in a topology where *bridging* them would do anything but short a line to a power rail, then you are using them incorrectly!  **You need to edit a schematic into your question**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been abandoned by the asker in unanswerable form, with no schematic ever being provided and no followup of the suggested investigations.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been abandoned by the asker in unanswerable form, with no schematic ever being provided and no followup of the suggested investigations.

Answer (score 0):

I think your USB resistor is broken or improperly soldered. This will stop the USB bootloader from working properly as you've observed.